# Apache Virtual Host Configuration

Tags: apache, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I am using Apache 2.4 on Raspbian and I want to create a virtual host to serve files on my external hard drive on my website. I searched it on the internet and found many guides to make it but this seemed the simplest: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/apache-virtual-host/

However, the files "httpd.conf" and "httpd-vhost.conf" which are mentioned in the guide do not exist in my system (I searched the whole system). Therefore I can't configure those files and hence, my virtual host. When I was searching the information about location of https.conf on the internet, I learnt that it does not exist anymore. However, I couldn't find the information about what to do in this situation.

I have been searching it online for hours but I couldn't find the answer. I do not know how to set up my virtual host. I would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: Raspbian is debian based if I recall correctly. Then most likely the apache http server will be packed in a similar manner: you should have a folder `/etc/apache2/sites-available` with examples. Also it probably is a good idea if you follow a debian or ubuntu guide for that, the one you mentioned appears to be more RedHat based. In general things are the same, obviously, but they may look different from time to time.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debian derivatives keep their config files in `/etc/apache2/`

To create a new virtual host, create a new config file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`. You can use `000-default.conf` as a template (but you'll need to add `ServerName` directives as you'll be creating a specific default host rather than the fallback).

Then run `a2ensite YOUR-CONFIG.conf` to turn it on, and `service apache2 restart` to restart the HTTP server so it picks up the new configuration.